# Hardys Inequality on Integrals

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

My PDE script lists a form of Hardy´s inequality which is not the common one:

---

Let $u\in C^\infty([0,\infty))$ and $\delta < -\frac{1}{2}$. Then:

$(\int_0^\infty |r^\delta u(r)|^2 dr)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \frac{2}{|2\delta+1|} (\int_0^\infty |r^{\delta+1}\partial_ru(r)|^2 dr)^\frac{1}{2}$

---

I´m interested in a proof of this inquality. Does anyone know how to do so?

I also noticed that the integrals might not be finite. So there must be some further assumption on u.